# I want to develop an app in android using indic font, also want to show indic font in dialog box

Tags: android

I have done an app to show tamil data on text view to putting elcutni.ttf in android asset folder for that. Then I made a fonts folder by using

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"fonts/vigyapti.ttf");
txt.setTypeface(tf);
```

I am showing tamil data on text view a sample tamil data is taken from random site and store it in the strings.xml file. How can I show data on text view and dialog box of indic fonts? Please help me to make app which contains all indic fonts. Please help me to show indic font data on dialog box and text view.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are on the right way, although maybe not the correct font. Have a look at this post to see if it helps:

http://lkalarani.blogspot.com/2011/04/tamil-in-android.html

Also, what is exactly the problem with the code you posted? Do you get an exception? If it's not correctly rendered, have you got any screenshots?

Comment: hi thanks how can i give u screen shots of my app also i tried this code:::: txt=(TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        txt.setText(this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
       R.string.app_name contains this कोलकाता के एएमआरआई अस्‍पताल के बेसमेंट में भीषण आग लगने से अफरातफरी मच गई है. अग्निकांड में अब तक 73 लोगों की मौत की पुष्टि की जा चुकी है और कई लोग जख्‍मी हैं   अन्ना  जरूरतमंदों  नेटवर्किन्ग नई दिल्ली but in my app in some phone it is distracted and in some phone it shows me only square...

Comment: You can post code using www.pastebin.com and to do images you can use http://tinypic.com/
Did you also have a look at the post I shared?